# Non-Negative Matrix Factorization - Estimating the Mean

Tags: equities, factor-models

How do you estimate the mean in a Non-Negative Matrix Factorization framework?

It is obvious and well known how to estimate the covariance matrix, how ever I also need the estimated mean. I'm assuming there is a way to estimate the mean via regression as there is with similar algorithm's such as PCA and this should already be derived for Non-Negative Matrix Factorization. I just can't find it in the literature and common frameworks do not provide this and only return the matrix factorization (MatLab, R ,Python exc...).

Using the terminology from [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nnmf.html).

`A` represents an `NxM` Matrix (Could be 1 + Returns or Volumes or generally any positive matrix). One can compute `nnmf(A)` to get `[W, H, D]` where `W*H` is a lower-rank approximation to `A`.

Is this as simple as computing the direct mean and covariance of `W*H` or am I missing something?

Comment: I am aware of the PCA of a covariance matrix and I have seen NNMF being applied to data. But how is NNMF applied to a covariance matrix? A covariance matrix is usually negative too. Is it transformed? In my experience NNMF is hard to interpret.

Comment: Please clarify which mean you want to estimate - Thank you

Comment: @vonjd Sure I updated the question a bit, I want the mean from the factorized result set `W, H , D` above.